# @font-face fonts break on mobile

Tags: html, css, font-face

When I'm using @font-face for desktop it works fine. When I resize to mobile some text breaks out of the wrapper.

I've used fontsquirrel.com to generate the font. I've tested it with other fonts (websafe fonts & google fonts) and they don't go out of the wrapper.

Is it possible that a font can break out of a wrapper? Or have I just used the wrong settings in fontsquirrel?

I can't add a jsfiddle because the problem only shows on native mobile.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share a snippet of the CSS you're using for the @font-face and specify which native mobile clients you're experiencing issues in (by editing your question above)?

Comment: Of course a font can break out of a wrapper. `<div style="height:1px">text</div>` does. I don't understand your remark about jsfiddle though. Mobiles can view jsfiddle pages too.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use overflow to accomplish this. If you dont want it to break out of the "box". Here's an example:

```css
div {
  background: lightgray;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In consectetur magna sed nulla auctor, at posuere enim tempus. Phasellus pretium nisl imperdiet, interdum elit vitae, aliquet augue. Suspendisse efficitur dui sit amet eleifend tempus. Curabitur tincidunt et mauris a viverra. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Vestibulum eu elit a dolor lacinia volutpat nec vitae elit. Aliquam leo ex, lacinia sed turpis at, semper elementum mi. Praesent eget vehicula dui, in tempor felis. Mauris lobortis dui eget mollis blandit. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
</div>
```